# AS3 Starling mobile project using large images - wont fit in sprite sheet

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am wondering if someone could suggest the best way to handle 6 large images that need to be used as an app tour.

I am using a sprite sheet for all other assets however I need to create a tour section in the app which shows 6 of the app screens with some parts highlighted with explanation on what that particular part does. The 6 screens are full size app images so 6 of these (640x960 x 6) does not fit in a sprite sheet.

A bit stuck as to what the best performance method would be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say it does not fit? You could easily pack all 6 images into a single 2048x2048 atlas. Even if you had more (or larger) images, you could then use Stage3D extended mode which allows 4096x4096 textures.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I was trying to pack in 12 640x960 which didn't fit but I didn't realise Starling offered 4096x4096